# .htaccess and folder protection - Should I create another .htacess file in another folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, password-protection

**.htaccess** file contains a list of rewrite rules and works fine,

**.htaccess** file is in the root directory,

**.htaccess** contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^index.php / [L,R=301]
```

How to password-protect a */secret* folder?

Should I add

```
AuthUserFile /secret/path/to/safedirectory/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

to **.htaccess** file that is in the root directory? Right after the code above, or at the very  beginning?

Or, I have to create another **.htaccess** file in the */secret* folder, and put **.htpasswd** into */secret/safedirectory* folder?

Thank you.

Comment: When you already have possible solutions, why not try all of them before posting

Comment: The second solution, with 2 .htaccess files doesn't work in my case, I've tried. It redirects to 401.shtml (and I don't understand, why) after entering a password (the first .htaccess file has more rewriterules, I've simplified it for this question). Once I remove .htaccess from the root folder, then it works (with no rewriterules). Also, it works, if I remove .htaccess from the secretfolder (it works, but doesn't ask the password). But, with both files it goes to 401 error. I can't understand why. That's why I'm asking and trying to understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put  this in the .htaccess in the secret directory?

```
 AuthUserFile /path/to/safedirectory/.htpasswd
 AuthGroupFile /dev/null
 AuthName EnterPassword
 AuthType Basic
 require valid-user
```

You have to put the .htaccess in the secret directory

Comment: yes. The first .htaccess is in the root directory. The second (with your code) .htaccess is in the /secret directory. And .htpasswd is in the /secret/safedirectory folder. The path is correct (tested by entering a password, works with no redirections to 401.shtml when I remove .htaccess from the root directory).